# Gedmo Tree getPath Error: Node is not related to this repository 500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException

Tags: tree, symfony, doctrine-extensions, stofdoctrineextensions

I am getting error:

```
Node is not related to this repository
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
```

UPDATE 1: it does not matter if I set up tree [repository with traits](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md#tree-repositories) or [extend abstract repository](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md#extend-abstract-repositores) the error is the same.

UPDATE 2: Full stack trace http://pastebin.com/TtaJnyzf

I want to output html tree with tree structure from database and specifically **I need to get path from root to selected node**. As I understand it, that is done with getPath() function.

I am using:

- Symfony v3.0.6;
- Doctrine v2.5.4
- StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle [1]

in order to manage Tree structure.

To setup Tree structure I used documentation on Symfony.com [2] followed by documentation on GitHub [3], [4], [5], [6].

So far I have a tree structure in database and i get html tree like this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Category;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class TreeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/tree", name="tree")
     */
    public function treeAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $repo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category');
        $options = array(
            'decorate' => true,
            'rootOpen' => '<ul>',
            'rootClose' => '</ul>',
            'childOpen' => '<li>',
            'childClose' => '</li>',
            nodeDecorator' => function($node)
            {
                return '<a href="/some_path/...">'. $node['title'] .'</a>';
            }
        );

        $htmlTree = $repo->childrenHierarchy(
            null, /* starting from root nodes */
            false, /* false: load all children, true: only direct */
            $options
        );

        return $this->render('tree/tree_show.html.twig', array('project_tree' => $htmlTree));
    }
}
```

I changed two lines in order to display path from the root of an tree element to selected item

```
nodeDecorator' => function($node) use ($repo)
{
    return '<a href="/project_path/'. implode('/', $repo->getPath($node)) .'">'. $node['title'] .'</a>';
}
```

As seen in [7] and [8] the function getPath() that supposed to return array of elements from the root to the selected item exists.

I think the problem may lie in this code block:

```
$repo->getPath($node)
```

- [1] [stofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) on GitHub;
- [2] [stofDoctrineExtensinsBundnle documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html) on Symfony.com;
- [3] [Gedmo Tree documentation](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md) on GitHub;
- [4] [Gedmo Tree > Tree Entity example](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md#tree-entity-example);
- [5] [Gedmo Tree > Basic Usage Example](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md#basic-usage-examples);
- [6] [Tree html output example](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md#customize-html-tree-output);
- [7] NestedTreeRepository uses [NestedTreeRepositoryTrait](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Entity/Repository/NestedTreeRepository.php)
- [8] NestedTreeRepositoryTrait has [function "getPath()"](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Traits/Repository/ORM/NestedTreeRepositoryTrait.php).

Please advise. 
Thank you for your time and knowledge.

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: @xabbuh I updated my question with stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working!

Here are the needed changes:

instead of

```
nodeDecorator' => function($node) use ($repo)
{
    return '<a href="/project_path/'. implode('/', $repo->getPath($node)) .'">'. $node['title'] .'</a>';
}
```

one should write

```
'nodeDecorator' => function($node) use ($repo)
{
    return '<a href="/project_path/'. @implode('/', $repo->getPath($repo->findOneBy(array('id' => $node['id'])))) .'">'. $node['title'] .'</a>';
}
```

and in Category class add

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getTitle();
}
```

That is it, path to each node now should be showing.